# How create library build from vite for including in html

Tags: javascript, vite

I use vite to build my library. But vite creates a build without isolating variables. Such a build cannot be included directly in html. Because variable names may overlap. And we see error like: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'y' has already been declared"

My config:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  define: {
    'process.env': {}
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, './src/main.js'),
      name: 'modal-help',
    },
    outDir: './',
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: 'script.js',
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  output: {
    format: 'esm',
    entryFileNames: 'script.js',
  }
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.